# Call Python from R, to use Arcmap requires Python 26

Tags: python, r, system, arcmap

I am trying to run a python script from R. Which is easy enough to do.

```
system('python Checkpythonverion.py')
```

file: Checkpythonverion.py

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

returns:

```
2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  3 2011, 15:34:33) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

However when I run a code calling the arcpy module (from arcgis)

File: Pythoncode.py

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Student\PythonDesktop10_0\Data\Westerville.gdb"
fc = "Streets"
distanceList = ["100 meters", "200 meters", "400 meters"]
for dist in distanceList:
    outName = fc+"_"+ dist[1]
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc,outName,dist)
    print " Finished Buffer"
```

Returns

> system('python PythonScript.py')
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "PythonScript.py", line 1, in 
>           import arcpy
>       ImportError: No module named arcpy
>       Warning message:
>       running command 'python PythonScript.py' had status 1

I know the reason.  Arcmap's arcpy only runs in python26.  The issue then is how can I change the default version of python called by the system.  I have tried a number of things including: changing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

**from:** C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

**to:**   C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\python.exe" "%1" %*

While also changing the user environmental variable "Path"

**from:** C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts

**to:**   C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\;C:\Python27\Scripts

After which from R:

```
>system('python Checkpythonverion.py')
```

still returns:

```
2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  3 2011, 15:34:33) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Thoughts?  It would be great if I could call the version of python I wanted from the R command line.  For instance system('python26 file.py').
Running: Windows 7, R 2.15.1
Installed: Python 25,26,27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well just figured it out... pretty simple

```
system('C:\\Python26\\ArcGIS10.0\\python.exe Checkpythonverion.py')
```

returns:

```
2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```